# Get URL of image in OneDrive

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I'm using LiveSDK in C#. Is there any way to get an URL (for example, url like this: https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=1ED5694B634A1579&resid=1ED5694B634A1579%21685&authkey=ANQwPScWiCxbILY) for a specified image file in order to put this link directly to the Image (Source property) control?
I dont want to download a Stream from OneDrive file, set it to a BitmapImage and put it to the Image control.

I know that OneDrive web app allows to create an URL for a selected file, but don't know if the SDK has such feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good example in MSDN Samples Page showing how to pull and use images from OneDrive.

`Photo Sky SampleThis sample demonstrates how to use the LiveSDK for pulling images from SkyDrive. In this sample you will learn how to use LiveSDK and request consent from the user to access his SkyDrive files and display the images in a Metro style application.`

Source: [PhotoSky - SkyDrive Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141)